# How to make csv file columns format properly in java?

Tags: java

I have a csv file where I am query my database to a csv file. But for some reason the data is not being accurate. As you can see in the image below of "my Result" in step_1 column the data looks accurate, but there $4 that needs to be shift into column step_2. Is there way you can help me solve this with my code below? thanks

My result

[image]

What I want to accomplish

[image]

```
public void exportData() throws IOException, SQLException {

    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    externalContext.setResponseContentType("text/csv");
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"all_salaries.csv\"");

    OutputStream out = externalContext.getResponseOutputStream();
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out);

    String sql = "SELECT "
            + "     job_class_cd \"JOB CLASS\", \n"
            + "     pay_grade \"PAY GRADE\",\n"
            + "     job_class_title, "
            + "     mou,"
            + "     mou_description,"
            + "     nvl(REGEXP_REPLACE(minimum_annual, '\\.[0-9]*', ''), ' ') \"MINIMUM ANNUAL\",\n"
            + "     nvl(REGEXP_REPLACE(maximum_annual, '\\.[0-9]*', ''), ' ') \"MAXIMUM ANNUAL\",\n"
            + "     nvl(salary_range || CASE WHEN min_step IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' ('  || to_char(MIN_STEP) || ')' END, ' ') \"SALARY RANGE (MIN STEP)\",\n"
            + "     nvl(rate_type, ' ') \"RATE TYPE\",\n"
            + "     nvl(flat_rate, ' ') \"FLAT RATE\",\n"
            + "     nvl(per_event_rate, ' ') \"PER EVENT RATE\",\n"
            + "     step_1,"
            + "     step_2,"
            + "     step_3,"
            + "     step_4,"
            + "     step_5,"
            + "     step_6,"
            + "     step_7,"
            + "     step_8,"
            + "     step_9,"
            + "     step_10,"
            + "     step_11,"
            + "     step_12,"
            + "     step_13,"
            + "     step_14,"
            + "     step_15"
            + " FROM myBean.va_v_vpay"
            + "       ORDER BY job_class_title, job_class_cd, pay_grade, rate_type desc";

    // MARK: CSV content header
    try {
        SqlRowSet rs = dataUtilityService.getJdbcTemplate().queryForRowSet(sql);
        writer.write("JOB CLASS, PAY GRADE, JOB_CLASS_TITLE");
        writer.write(", MOU");
        writer.write(", MOU_DESCRIPTION");
        writer.write(", MINIMUM ANNUAL, MAXIMUM ANNUAL");
        writer.write(", SALARY RANGE (MIN STEP), RATE TYPE");
        writer.write(", FLAT RATE, PER EVENT RATE");
        writer.write(", STEP_1, STEP_2");
        writer.write(", STEP_3, STEP_4");
        writer.write(", STEP_5, STEP_6");
        writer.write(", STEP_7, STEP_8");
        writer.write(", STEP_9, STEP_10");
        writer.write(", STEP_11, STEP_12");
        writer.write(", STEP_13, STEP_14");
        writer.write(", STEP_15");
        writer.write(",");
        writer.write("\n");

        while (rs.next()) {

            writer.write(rs.getString(1));
            writer.write(",");
            writer.write(rs.getString(2));
            writer.write(",");
            writer.write(rs.getString(3));
            writer.write(",");
            writer.write(rs.getString(4));
            writer.write(",");
            writer.write(rs.getString(5));
            writer.write(",");
            writer.write('"');
            writer.write(rs.getString(6));
            writer.write('"');
            writer.write(",");
            writer.write('"');
            writer.write(rs.getString(7));
            writer.write('"');
            writer.write(",");
            writer.write(rs.getString(8));
            writer.write(",");
            writer.write(rs.getString(9));
            writer.write(",");
            writer.write(rs.getString(10));
            writer.write(",");
            writer.write(rs.getString(11));
            writer.write(",");
            writer.write('"');
            writer.write(rs.getString(12));
            writer.write(",");
            writer.write('"');
            writer.write(rs.getString(13));
            writer.write('"');
            writer.write(rs.getString(14));
            writer.write(rs.getString(15));
            writer.write(rs.getString(16));
            writer.write(rs.getString(17));
            writer.write(rs.getString(18));
            writer.write(rs.getString(19));
            writer.write(rs.getString(20));
            writer.write(rs.getString(21));
            writer.write(rs.getString(22));
            writer.write(rs.getString(23));
            writer.write(rs.getString(24));
            writer.write(rs.getString(25));
            writer.write(rs.getString(26));
            writer.write(",");
            writer.write("\n");

        }

    } finally {

        if (writer != null) {

            // MARK: Close and flush the  OutputStream
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

        }
    }
    facesContext.responseComplete();

}
```

**Result from textEdit:**

> STEP_1, STEP_2, STEP_3, STEP_4, STEP_5, STEP_6, STEP_7, STEP_8, STEP_9, STEP_10, STEP_11, STEP_12, STEP_13, STEP_14, STEP_15,
>   9206,0,DIRECTOR,36,TEST," "," ",5736 (1),Hourly, , "      $57.36","      $58.94",      $60.56,      $62.23,      $65.70,      $69.37,      $73.23,      $77.31,      $79.44,      $81.62,      $83.87,      $86.18,   ,
>   9206,0,DIRECTOR,TEST UNI," "," ",5736 (1),Biweekly, , "   $4,588.80","   $4,715.20",   $4,844.80,   $4,978.40,   $5,256.00,   $5,549.60,   $5,858.40,   $6,184.80,   $6,355.20,   $6,529.60,   $6,709.60,   $6,894.40,   ,
>   9206,0," $119,767"," $179,943",5736 (1),Annual, , " $119,767.68"," $123,066.72", $126,449.28, $129,936.24, $137,181.60, $144,844.56, $152,904.24, $161,423.28, $165,870.72, $170,422.56, $175,120.56, $179,943.84,   ,
>   2208,0,TRAINEE,00,NON,"  $41,760","  $41,760", ,Hourly,      $20.00, " "," ", , , , , , , , , , ,   ,

Comment: What do you think will happen when the $ amount contains a `,` ? (ie "$4,567.90")

Comment: as you can see in my step_1 it is containing `,` but as you can see '$4` is not being shift with my step_2 numbers. Something is off with the formatting.  I try to wrap my string with `writer.write('"');` but it did not work properly. Only it works on my step_1 , as you can see in the image.

Comment: @corn3lius do you get my problem and what I want to accomplish?

Comment: Can you post a couple of lines from the csv output. csv as writen and what excel imports are not always the same thing.

Comment: The output of the csv is the image of "My result"

Comment: csv is a string, not a picture.

Comment: I know, the output of csv is shown above as in the image. I have all the code that generates to csv in my code above.

Comment: It is so hard to see what the image (excel cells) contains. It is always better to post data as text not images. Besides your code looks wrong so I am not sure even step_1 is correct

Comment: if you know how to do in xls format , please I love to see the working code. @JoakimDanielson step_1 should be correct , but the rest I think you need to wrap with `writer.write('"');`. However, I need some help.

Comment: Open your csv file in a normal text editor and do copy and paste into your question, it's not hard.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson  please see updated question

Comment: See my answer instead. It looks like you removed some of the column headers but not the corresponding data...

Comment: I would recommend you use a better Csv writer like Solr http://lucene.apache.org/solr/7_5_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/internal/csv/writer/CSVWriter.html

Comment: @Nikhil can you please show me a working code to see how it slightly working with `solr`, first time hearing about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have numbers as a formatted string you will need to quote all the strings that contain a comma.

```
// Takes some value and coverts it to a quoted string. 
String getQuotedCell(Object o){ 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("\"");
    sb.append(o).append("\",");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Example here [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@mark_boyle_sp/FabulousPlumShoutcast)

I would recommend though you just output the numeric value as opposed to a string. Spreadsheet programs can format the number as a dollar amount very easily.

sort of like this.

```
while (rs.next()) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    for (int i =1; i <= 26; i++) {
       sb.append(rs.getObject(i)).append(",")
    }
    sb.append("\n");
    writer.write(sb.toString()); // write row.
```